# How to fix fatal error? git hub

Tags: ruby, git

i'm trying to run the script from here: https://www.uludum.org/courses/118-how-to-run-your-own-bitcoin-arbitrage-bot/subsections/2164-installation

You can try follow yourself and test results

I have followed it exactly and yet when I go to open the program I get this and I have no idea how to fix it? ANY HELP IS BIG HELP. I have run git init in this folder:C:\Ruby200\bin I think that is the right folder? How can I know where to run it?

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
`block in materialize': Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources (Bun
dler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_
set.rb:85:in `map!'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_
set.rb:85:in `materialize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:133:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/defin
ition.rb:178:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:13:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:12
7:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:13
2:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage-2.3.0/lib/rbtc_a
rbitrage.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage-2.3.0/lib/rbtc_a
rbitrage.rb:2:in `chdir'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage-2.3.0/lib/rbtc_a
rbitrage.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in
 `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rbtc_arbitrage-2.3.0/bin/rbtc:4
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/rbtc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/rbtc:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever you're running is requiring a gem you don't have installed.

Run `gem install minitest`

Comment: Ran it and no luck still

Comment: The error would be different now - what does it say?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/C4Tbre4F thanks. I reinstalled it with 64bit dev kit and 64 ruby this time seems to of helped too. What you think of this error now?

Comment: any idea to what it could bE?

Comment: anything? been stuck for a while

Comment: is `rbtc_simple` a ruby file you're trying to run?

Comment: I think so. The guide just says type rbtc_simple and then it should open without these errros